# Voting convention a bit too harsh

Tags: discussion

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334550/integrate-a-php-page-into-prestashop) as I've been having trouble meeting requirements. For me the question appeared to be quite clear as well as the title. I was hoping that there might exist a quick hack so Prestashop would accept linking to a standalone PHP page as is possible for other scripts.

Unfortunately, the question got quickly downvoted. This might have the undesireable effect that people capable of answering the question might turn away at seeing the post score (minus points = bad question).

Just what exactly defines quality? I'd have thought that putting up a concise post would at least have the merit of going straight to the point.

Comment: *"This might have the undesirable effect that people capable of answering the question might turn away at seeing the post score"* - that's kind of the whole point, don't you think? I'm sure it's undesirable *to you*, but voting is done on behalf of everyone *else*.

Comment: @Aarobot So people who don't have a clue about a given topic are the ones evaluating a question? That sounds "logical" :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The current revision of the question is a lot better than the original:

> Is there any way to integrate an existing PHP script with Prestashop?

This shows little research effort on your part, which is not to say that you didn't *do* any research, it just means you didn't show us what you found.

The [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) guidelines are linked to in the sidebar when you're asking a question.  I think you ran afoul of the "Do your homework" and "Be specific" sections of those guidelines.

Answer (score 8):

I'd agree with Bill as it stands the current question is much better.  I think it's pretty rare that you'll be able simply ask a question without any context and get a response that you find acceptable.  Invariably you'll get down votes or you'll have people ask for more detail.

You have to understand that few of us have enough context to reasonably answer your question.  If you happen to luck into someone who does, then great, but the rest of us need more detail to be able to help you.  If, looking at your question, there's not enough for a reasonable person to answer it meaningfully with the information given, then you probably deserve the down vote.

Personally, I don't like downvoting people who are asking for help (esp. new people, though you don't really fit that category).  I'd probably ask for more information first if the question were brand new.  It's hard to fault someone for down voting your original question though with as little information as it had.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Jon Skeet said SO was a good exercice in communication and I'm starting to understand how. That and positionning oneself in someone's elses boots (something I could easily do before but have difficulty with now). The overall quality of my posts is ok and it's just a bit frustrating for form to get in the way of content resulting in no solution coming up. As the original question here was below the quality standard I'll do a postmortem to see I can improve future questions.